# Power spectral density of freely diffusing particle versus trapped particle?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, brownian-motion, stochastic-processes

Recently I was exposed to [optical tweezer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_tweezers) experiment in which we pulled an axonal membrane (of a chicken embryo neuronal cell) using an optically trapped 2.4 $\mu$m diameter polystyrene bead. A lot of questions came to my mind after this experiment since my background is neither biology nor physics. In this particular experiment the trapped particle's position is sensed by a photodiode setup and its power spectrum looks something like below (in log-log plot) :

[image: POWER SPECTRAL DENSITY of a brownian particle in a harmonic potential well]

This is a power spectral density (psd) corresponding to a brownian particle *but* in a "harmonic potential well". So I have 3 questions:

- ***For a "pure" brownian particle (i.e. a wiener process) the psd varies ~ $1/f^2$ where $f$ is the frequency. Why $1/f^2$ ?*** Can I get some reference about the derivation of this. I can intuitively understand why lower frequency components must contain higher energy and higher frequency modes contain low energy by looking at a brownian particle's displacement time series data.But I would like to get a light mathematical feel for this.
- Secondly I would like to know ***why there is a flat region in psd for lower frequency region in a optically trapped brownian particle in a harmonic potential?*** The power spectrum now has 2 regions, one the diffusive behavior in higher frequencies and viscous behavior in lower frequencies. And here psd ~ $1/(f^2 + {f_c}^2)$ where the cutoff frequency $f_c$ which is related to parameters like stiffness, viscosity of the medium etc. But I dont have the intuition for this explanation.
- ***Is the statement "The brownian particle trapped in a symmetrical harmonic potential exhibits gaussian distribution in displacements" true?*** If so can someone explain me why?

---

**UPDATE** : I got the answer of question number 1 from wikipedia page on [brownian noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_noise).

Answer (score 1):

An intuitive answer to question 2

For unconstrained brownian motion the power spectral density would have a $\frac{1}{f^2}$ character all the way down to 0 Hz. However you now have brownian motion that is constrained in an harmonic potential.

The high frequency movements will have a smaller position amplitude and will not feel the boundaries set by the constraints.

The low frequency movements will have a larger amplitude. (An extreme example is of course 0Hz motion) These low frequency movements will quickly run into the boundaries and be damped.

The cutoff frequency will be the eigenfrequency of the particle in the harmonic potential well.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question 3:

Generally, the position distribution of a Brownian particle trapped in the potential $U(x)$ is given by the Boltzmann distribution $\frac1Z\,\mathrm e^{-U(x)/kT}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually one of my friends gave me this explanation recently. Can you share any link for the derivation?